# Find the derivative for $f(x) = \sqrt{x+2}$ by definition

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Use the definition of derivatives to show that the derivative of  $f(x) = \sqrt{x+2}$   is
>   $$
> f'(x) = \frac12(x+2)^{-\frac12}
> $$

My proof so far:

Given $\epsilon > 0$ , $\exists \delta(\epsilon) > 0$ s.t. $|x-c| < \delta(\epsilon)$, then $$\left| \frac{\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{c+2}}{x-c} - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{c+2}}\right| <\epsilon$$

Is this a standard approach? Not sure how i would find $\delta$ less than $x-c$ or what my $\delta =$ min would be.

Comment: You probably don't need to go all the way back to the definition of a limit of a function.  You just need to evaluate $\lim \limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to start from the definition of a limit.  Just use the definition of the derivative of a function $$f'(x) := \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ and the rules for evaluating limits.

To see how this is done explicitly scroll over the region below.

> $$\require{cancel}\begin{align}f'(x) &= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \\ &= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x+h+2}-\sqrt{x+2}}{h} \\ &= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x+h+2}-\sqrt{x+2}}{h}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{x+h+2}+\sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt{x+h+2}+\sqrt{x+2}} \\ &= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{(x+h+2)-(x+2)}{h(\sqrt{x+h+2}+\sqrt{x+2})} \\ &= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\cancel h}{\cancel h(\sqrt{x+h+2}+\sqrt{x+2})} \\ &= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h+2}+\sqrt{x+2}} \\ &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+2}}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

we have $$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{\sqrt{x+2+h}-\sqrt{x+2}}{h}=\frac{x+2+h-x-2}{h(\sqrt{x+2+h}+\sqrt{x+2})}$$ and then you can compute the Limit for $h$ tends to zero.